# How to do ROLLUP/SUBTOTALS on hierarchical defined data with SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get a "ROLLUP" or "SUBTOTALS" on some hierarchical data defined like this:

```
ZoneId ParentZoneId Name       Qty  
1      NULL         Zone 1     1    
2      1            Zone 1.2   2    
4      2            Zone 1.2.1 4    
5      2            Zone 1.2.2 5    
3      1            Zone 1.3   3    
6      NULL         Zone 2     6   
7      6            Zone 2.1   7    
8      6            Zone 2.2   8
```

To find subtotals by zone.

To achieve that I calculate a "StructureId" that "solves" each zone hierarchy and use the following query:

```
select
    z.ZoneId,
    z.ParentZoneId,
    z.Name,
    z.StructureId,
    z.Qty,
    sum(subt.Qty) SubTotal
from 
    dbo.Zone as z join dbo.Zone as subt on
        subt.StructureId like z.StructureId + '%'
group by
    z.ZoneId,
    z.ParentZoneId,
    z.Name,
    z.StructureId,
    z.Qty
order by
    Name;
```

So I actually get the correct result:

```
ZoneId ParentZoneId Name       Qty  StructureId  SubTotal
1      NULL         Zone 1     1    1.           15
2      1            Zone 1.2   2    1.2.         11
4      2            Zone 1.2.1 4    1.2.4.        4
5      2            Zone 1.2.2 5    1.2.          5
3      1            Zone 1.3   3    1.3.          3
6      NULL         Zone 2     6    6.           21
7      6            Zone 2.1   7    6.7.          7
8      6            Zone 2.2   8    6.8.          8
```

But I need to use a procedure to calculate the StructureId, so I would like to know, Is it possible to solve this using some ROLLUP, CUBE or other SELECT option in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an oldish one but I stumbled upon it and found some time to answer (not independently of me being fond of Common Table Expressions).  So here goes the code:

```
with CTE (ZoneId, ParentZoneId, ChildId, SumQty) 
as (
  select z.ZoneId, z.ParentZoneId, null as childid, coalesce(z.Qty,0) as SumQty
  from Zone z

  union all

  select z.ZoneId, z.ParentZoneId, v.ZoneId as childid, coalesce(v.SumQty,0) as SumQty
  from Zone z inner join CTE v on z.ZoneId = v.ParentZoneId
)
select z.*, v.SumQty
from (select ZoneId, sum(SumQty) as SumQty from CTE group by ZoneId) v
inner join Zone z on v.ZoneId=z.ZoneId
```

It is worth getting somewhat acquainted with CTEs beforehand (WRT recursive queries see the [relevant MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) for example).  The CTE expression selects each record for its own Qty once (the so called "Anchor Member Definition", top part of `UNION ALL`) and once for each of its children (total for that child, the so called "Recursive Member Definition", bottom part of `UNION ALL`).

While trying to understand the code it's worth changing the main select to `select * from CTE order by 1` to see what's going on behind the scenes.  (NB the `ChildId` is only in there to help this "debugging"...  Also note that the `coalesce` functions are there to prevent `NULL` `Qty` values to propagate — which may or may not be the behavior needed; it's indifferent here but in most cases I've found that's what one wants.)

The main `select` clause then sums up quantities that directly or through children belong to the same `ZoneId` and joins back the rest of the attributes.